# router-link is not working properly?

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I was working on angular 2 web application I was new to angular 2.I have a problem with "router-link" it was not working properly.I created router file ,and I also added path of the component file.

Below is my code:
   This is router file code, I tried in internet also but no use.In which file was facing the problem please help out this.

router.ts:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RegisterComponent } from './forms/register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './forms/login/login.component';
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '' , component:LoginComponent},
    { path: 'signup', component: RegisterComponent},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

register.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Validators, FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html'
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

        error = '';
    loading = false;
    myForm: FormGroup;

    events: {}[] = [];

  constructor(private fb : FormBuilder,
                private router : Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
          this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        username: ['', Validators.required],
        email: ['', Validators.required],
        passwords: this.fb.group({
            password: ['', Validators.required],
            confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
            })
        });
  }

}
```

register.html the main code:

```
    <div class="form-header login-header">
      <h3>Hello User!!!</h3>
      <p>Already have an account? <a [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a></p>
    </div>
```

On clicking login link it must be redirect to login page but it was not working please help me.

Comment: can u please add the error you are getting in your question? or just add this url ['../login'] instead of ['login']

Comment: I am not getting any error.The problem is it was not redirecting to login page.When I click on "<a [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>" this login it was not redirecting.

Comment: use ../login instead of /login and check

Comment: This is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<a (click)="router.navigate(['/login']);"> </a>
```

OR

add a function in your html

```
<a (click)="goToPage('login')"> </a>
```

and in your component, call the function

```
private goToPage(pageName: string) {
    this.router.navigate([`${pageName}`]);
  }
```

Comment: Is there any problem with my app.router file ?

Comment: @phani I have edited the answer, pls find if it works for you

Comment: What is this "pageName" in the goToPage() function.

Comment: I tried with goToName function  it was not redirecting but function was not working.

Comment: @phani,,, the function name is "goToPage", not "goToName",,, i hope you have given it properly..  "pageName" is the name of your page that you are passing from the function (click)="goToPage('login')".  Here the value for pageName is 'login', since login value passed from the html

Comment: "goToName" function is working but it was not redirecting.I think the problem with my app.router file please check that file.